# How to filter a collection using a list of predicates

Tags: kotlin, collections, filtering

I have a list of elements, for example:

```
val myList = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

The list could be of any type, this is just an example.
Now I have a list of predicates of arbitrary length:

```
val myPredicates = listOf({myInt: Int -> myInt > 1}, {myInt: Int -> myInt%2 == 0})
```

How do I filter the list by applying all the predicates, in order of the list, to `myList` and get the result in a new list?  I feel like the answer lies somewhere in using the `reduce` or `fold` operator, but the answer is eluding me.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to only keep the items that matches all predicates?

Comment: Correct.  Like chaining predicates like so: `myList.filter(predicate1).filter(predicate2)` but you don't know the number of predicates ahead of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is using [all](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/all.html) on the predicates list in your `filter` call like this:

```kotlin
myList.filter { elt -> myPredicates.all { it(elt) } }
```

The part `myPredicates.all { it(elt) }` returns true when all predicates are true for the given element `elt`.

Comment: Wow, deceptively simple.  I feel stupid for not figuring that out myself.  Thanks.

Comment: Haha no worries, it's easy to miss simple things :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to first combine all the predicates into one predicate (`(T) -> Boolean`) first, using `fold`, then apply that predicate using the built in `filter` method.

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.filter(predicates: Iterable<(T) -> Boolean>) =
    predicates.fold({ true }) { acc: (T) -> Boolean, next ->
        { acc(it) && next(it) }
    }.let { this.filter(it) }

fun main() {
    val myList = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
    val myPredicates = listOf({myInt: Int -> myInt > 2}, {myInt: Int -> myInt%2 == 0})
    println(myList.filter(myPredicates))
    // [4, 6]
}
```

Because of the short-circuiting nature of `&&` and the order of `acc(it)` followed by `next(it)`, each predicate will get run in order, and if any one produces `false`, the rest will not get run.

Comment: Isn't it a bit contrived compared to just evaluating all predicates in place inside a regular `filter`? What would be the benefit of this approach? I guess a bunch of capturing lambdas would have to be created there, so I'm not sure it outweighs the iterators creation of the naive approach.

Comment: @Joffrey I saw the question mentioning `fold` and got tunnel visioned. Your answer is clearly better!